# Evaluate Geometric Sum

Tags: algebra-precalculus, summation, geometric-series

I have the following sum to evaluate: 
$$\sum\limits_{n=1}^{\infty}\frac{n}{2^{n+1}}$$
My professor says that I can evaluate this through "differentiating the geometric series" but I am not quite sure what that means. I already know that this converges to $1$, just not sure how to prove.

Comment: See [this](https://math.stackexchange.com/questions/30732/how-can-i-evaluate-sum-n-0-inftyn1xn).

Answer (score 5, accepted):

A simpler way: let $S=\sum_{n\geq 0}\frac{n}{2^{n+1}}$ (the series is obviously absolutely convergent). Then

$$ S = 2S-S = \sum_{n\geq 1}\frac{n}{2^n}-\sum_{n\geq 1}\frac{n}{2^{n+1}}=\sum_{n\geq 0}\frac{n+1}{2^{n+1}}-\sum_{n\geq 1}\frac{n}{2^{n+1}} $$
hence
$$ S = \frac{1}{2}+\sum_{n\geq 1}\frac{1}{2^{n+1}} = \frac{1}{2}+\frac{1}{2}=\color{red}{1}.$$

Comment: Wonderful +1${}{}$

Answer (score 3):

**Hint:** recall that $$\frac{1}{1-x}=\sum_{n=0}^{\infty}x^n$$

differentiate both sides of this equation and multiply by $x$. Then substitute $x=\frac{1}{2}$.

In particular note that
$$\frac{d}{dx} \sum_{n=0}^{\infty} x^n=\sum_{n=0}^\infty \frac{d}{dx} x^n=\sum_{n=0}^\infty n \cdot x^{n-1}$$
on the right hand side of the equation.

Comment: I think you might want to substitute $x = \frac{1}{2}$ instead.

Comment: @orlp excuse me :)