# Proof explanation of $\sum_{i=1}^{n} \lfloor\log\left(\frac{n}{i}\right)\rfloor$

Tags: summation, proof-explanation, computational-complexity

$(1)$ The first relation.
$$
\left\lfloor \log_2\frac{n}{i} \right\rfloor=j 
\Longleftrightarrow 2^j \leq \frac{n}{i} < 2^{j+1}
\Longleftrightarrow \frac{n}{2^{j+1}} < i \leq \frac{n}{2^j} 
\space\space
$$

Therefore, $(2)$ The second relation as follows
$$
\sum_{i=1}^n\left\lfloor \log_2\frac{n}{i} \right\rfloor\leq \sum_{j=1}^{\lfloor \log_2n \rfloor}j\cdot\left(\frac{n}{2^{j+1}}+1\right)=O(\log^2n)+n \cdot \sum_{j=1}^{\infty}{\frac{j}{2^{j+1}}}=O(\log^2n)+n
$$

I don't know how can we get $(2)$ from $(1)$; Moreover, why and how can we simplify $(2)$ like that.

Comment: @Arthur sorry for my typo. I will add it now.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

By $(1)$, the number of integers $i$ such that $\left\lfloor \log_2\frac{n}{i} \right\rfloor=j$ is
$$\left\lfloor \frac n{2^j}\right\rfloor-\left\lceil\frac n{2^{j+1}}\right\rceil+1\le\frac n{2^j}-\frac n{2^{j+1}}+1=\frac n{2^{j+1}}+1,$$
whence the $\le$ in $(2).$

For the next $=,$ use that
$$\sum_{j=1}^{\lfloor \log_2n \rfloor}j=\frac{\lfloor \log_2n \rfloor(\lfloor \log_2n \rfloor+1)}2\le \frac{(\log_2n)(\log_2n+1)}2=O(\log_2^2n).$$

Finally, [$$\sum_{j=1}^{\infty}{\frac{j}{2^{j+1}}}=1.$$](https://math.stackexchange.com/questions/2546343)

Comment: Thank you. I wish you all the best.